# Difference between df.loc['col name'], df.loc[index]['col name'] and df.loc[index, 'col name'] in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with a column name 'Store'. If I want to retrieve the column, the following lines work equally well - `df['Store']` or `df[:]['Store']` or `df[:,'Store']`.

What is the difference between the two? And should one be used over the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.loc[index, 'col name']` is more idiomatic and preferred, especially if you want to filter rows

Demo: for 1.000.000 x 3 shape DF

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**6,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [27]: %timeit df[df.a < 0.5]['a']
10 loops, best of 3: 45.8 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit df.loc[df.a < 0.5]['a']
10 loops, best of 3: 45.8 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit df.loc[df.a < 0.5, 'a']
10 loops, best of 3: 37 ms per loop
```

For construction where you need only one column and don't filter rows like `df[:]['Store']` - it's better to use simply `df['Store']`:

```
In [30]: %timeit df[:]['a']
1000 loops, best of 3: 436 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit df.loc[:]['a']
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.9 µs per loop

In [36]: %timeit df['a'].loc[:]
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.5 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit df.loc[:, 'a']
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit df['a']
The slowest run took 5.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.17 µs per loop
```

Unconditional access of multiple columns:

```
In [34]: %timeit df[['a','b']]
10 loops, best of 3: 22 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit df.loc[:, ['a','b']]
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
```